# what is a better choice to hold a range when being queried by linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, collections, dictionary

I need to save a set of ranges of integers so then I can query them using linq like below :

```
int param = 10;
var matched = from item in items 
           where param >= item.min && param <= item.max;
```

a `list of Tuples` or a `Dictionary` or `list of KeyValuePairs` or ... . which one is a better choice ? ( I don't want to create a custom class of mine ).

Comment: A `List<Tuple<int,int>>` is most obvious... Depends a little on how you (want to) make them.

Comment: The advantage of a custom class would be that you could make it a struct which is more effective for such small amounts of data.

Comment: @HenkHolterman : the list is a static field of class and members are added at design time .

Comment: @MrFox : thank you , how about in compare to array ( as RB. answered )?

Comment: @mohsen.d An array of a struct consisting of 2 `ints` would have similarly low memory requirements, and high performance as the array solution I suggested. However, you explicitly rejected creating a new class in your question hence why I did not suggest it!

Comment: Actually the double array would be very good, the only thing is that you have to do a multiplication to find the right position in the internal array, but they are like 1 tick. And structs may also have other disadvantages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not a simple 2 dimensional array? This will have the lowest memory requirements, and the LINQ query you suggest will execute in linear time.

Pseudocode:

```
int param = 10;
// Define min and max array indices for readability.
public const int min = 0;
public const int max = 1;

int[,] myValues = {
    { 1, 50 }, 
    { 2, 3  },
    { 5, 60 }};

var matches = 
    from  item in myValues
    where param <= item[min] && 
          param >= item[max];
```